# Powershell Parse Date ISO8601

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have a date string in what I think is ISO8601 format (although I'm not 100% sure), e.g.

`20200210T165905+0000`

I want to parse this using powershell and have tried the following

```
$Date = "20200210T165905+0000"
$DatePattern = "yyyyMMdd\THHmmss\+zzzz"
$DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Date, $DatePattern, $null)
```

But I get the following error

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, think i got it - I neede to omit the `\+` escaped characted from my pattern, such that i reads `yyyyMMdd\THHmmsszzzz`. That seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dateformat you have requires a different pattern where the Time zone information is handled by `K`.

`+0000` means that the date is in UTC time (offset 0). If you remove that, the date string is parsed as if it is a LOCAL DateTime, giving you false information (unless you live in a part of the world where UTC is the same as the local time)

```
$Date = "20200210T165905+0000"
$DatePattern = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssK"
$DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Date, $DatePattern, $null)
$DateTime
```

Returns (in my NL Locale => UTC + 1)

> ```
> 10-2-2020 17:59:05
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `\+` escaped character from the pattern seems to fix it for me, i.e.,

`$DatePattern = "yyyyMMdd\THHmmsszzzz"`